# Same router, same cat5e cable, but different speeds between two computers

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, cable, wired

I can plug my Windows 7 laptop (an [MSI GE60](http://www.msi.com/product/nb/GE60_0NC.html#hero-overview)) directly into the router using a cat5e Ethernet cable, and it pulls 150-170 Mbps, no problem.

But if I unplug that same Ethernet cable from the laptop and plug it into a desktop (also using Windows 7), it will pull only 68-80 Mbps. Am I missing some kind of setting on my desktop or something that is limiting the speed?

The NIC in the desktop is a Realtek PCIe FE Family controller.  I tried my other desktop—which I built myself (and is running Windows 8.1)—and that also will pull a max of only 60-80 Mbps.  The second desktop I tested has a Realtek GBE PCIe Family controller NIC. I set it to 1.0 Gbps, no change; set it to auto negotiate, no difference; set it to 100 Mbps, no difference.

What is it about my laptop that will allow me to get the speed I pay for, but my desktops are getting only about half?

Comment: Note that if autonegotiate is disabled on one end, but enabled on another, [it will result in a poor connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_mismatch).

Comment: I'd look into Flow Control, QoS/WMM.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I finally figured it all out. It was a hardware problem and nothing else.

The first desktop I connected only had a 10/100 ethernet connection on the motherboard.

The second desktop I was connecting, was connected to a second router, that was connected to the first router, but the second router only supported 10/100 speeds.

I appreciate all the help, especially [Giacomo1968's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/874347/same-router-same-cat5e-cable-but-different-speeds-between-two-computers/874779#comment1163820_874347) for mentioning it sounded like a 100/1000 problem because that's exactly what it was.

*Note: Diagram image link is no longer valid and has been removed.*